# Customizing `\textcite` brackets with `authoryear` style in `biblatex`

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

The citation style in the second line is the default `\textcite`. It does not even look right to say 'see' and mention the year. Instead, the author year should follow in brackets (or without the brackets if some feel it is redundant).

What I want is something like the third line, but the year's link must be take the reader to the bibliography entry.

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
    @article{wu2019method,
        title={A method to identify weak points of interconnection of renewable energy resources},
        author={Wu, Di and Aldaoudeyeh, Al~Motasem and Javadi, Milad and Ma, Feng and Tan, Jin and Jiang, John N and others},
        journal={International Journal of Electrical Power \& Energy Systems},
        volume={110},
        pages={72--82},
        year={2019},
        publisher={Elsevier}
    }
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue3, citebordercolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear,refsection=chapter,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{cite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{cite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}



\begin{document}

    \cite{wu2019method}

    \textcite[see][pages 15-28]{wu2019method}

    (see [Wu et al. 2019], pages 15-28)

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\parencite` for the second example, not `\textcite`.  Getting square brackets inside is a lot more work. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: Because, for example, if you redefine `\parencite` to use `[...]` inside it, when you don't have a pre-note or post-note, you'll end up with ([Author, 2019]) which seems awfully redundant.

Comment: This is possible, if not as simple as a single `\Declare...CiteDelims`, but as Alan Munn points out this way of citing contains quite a few more or less redundant brackets culminating in the ridiculous "([Author, 2019])". I would go for the normal `\parencite` here. If you want you can get square brackets instead of round brackets with `\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}`.

Comment: Any news here? Can you tell us the desired output for the cases `\cite{wu2019method}`, `\cite[34-36]{wu2019method}`, `\cite[cf.][]{wu2019method}`, `\cite[see][34-36]{wu2019method}` please? (Or the same for `\textcite` if you want that modified.)

Comment: @moewe. The closest I get is 

`\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}`

with `\parencite`. This is good enough for me since it automatically places the parentheses and brackets. I am still curious about getting `\parencite` to give exactly the desired result (i.e., square brackets encircle all of the authoryear, not only the year).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but you need to dig a bit deeper than just high-level `biblatex` or `biblatex-ext` commands like `\Declare...CiteDelims`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue3, citebordercolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true}

\DeclareFieldFormat{medparencite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkouterparencitedelims]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[medparencite]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
  \parencite{sigfridsson}

  \parencite[380]{sigfridsson}

  \parencite[cf.][]{sigfridsson}

  \parencite[see][381]{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: ([Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998])//([Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998], p. 380)//(cf. [Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998])//(see [Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998], p. 381)]

---

Just for fun we can implement a `biblatex-ext`-like interface here

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=DodgerBlue3, citebordercolor=DodgerBlue3, colorlinks=true}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\DeclareMedCiteDelims}{%
  \extblx@declareciteddelims{med}}

\newrobustcmd*{\UndeclareMedCiteDelims}{%
  \extblx@undeclareciteddelims{med}}

\newrobustcmd*{\DeclareMedCiteDelimsAlias}{%
  \@ifstar
    {\extblx@declareciteddelims@alias@i{med}}
    {\extblx@declareciteddelims@alias{med}}}

\RegisterCiteDelims{med}{parencite}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extblx@medparencitedelims}{%
  \csuse{mkmed\blx@delimcontext delims}{#1}}
\makeatother

\DeclareMedCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkouterparencitedelims]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[extblx@medparencitedelims]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
  \parencite{sigfridsson}

  \parencite[380]{sigfridsson}

  \parencite[cf.][]{sigfridsson}

  \parencite[see][381]{sigfridsson}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

the output is the same.